# bcrypt and postgresql. What data type should be used?

Tags: python, postgresql, bcrypt

On flask-bcrypt extension, the encrypted string is stored as bytes object like
this (with python 3.5):

```
>>> user.password
b'$2b$12$3UutBDuGIrxp2z95alVTp.0HO3qQEtk7O/emR0UC27aNaJKC/WCU.'
```

But, when that string stored on postgresql it's converted and become like
this:

```
>>> user.password
'\\x243262243132244a546d7673453238354c754a497a4a334f37644a307559672f52796a486a526c4f443431536f387748544132303077447176555675'
```

Of course, it won't pass flask-bcrypt check password. I tried to `encode` the
password before save it to database and whenever check password is called I
decode it back. And it works.

My question is, what data type should I use? Am I have to use `BLOB` data
type on postgresql? Or is what I've done above (`encode` and `decode`) the right thing to do?
I don't have this issue when using sqlite3.

Comment: Show the code where you store and retrieve those values

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto do you mean the user model?

Comment: should be stored as text

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360362/5320906)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to convert the bytes to a python string (as all the bytes are ascii characters) then you can store it in a text (or other character type) column

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using BYTEA data type at the Postgresql. I think problem occurs while writing byte array into VARCHAR datatype in Postgre. This might be related to database encoding and the details of that conversion from byte to varchar.