# flask-bcrypt - ValueError: Invalid salt

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I was finishing up a simple user login with Flask and flask-Bcrypt. However, when trying to login with a user that is stored in my database, I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: Invalid salt
```

models.py

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="author", lazy="dynamic")

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.name)
```

views.py

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter(User.name == form.username.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            flash("you were just logged in!")
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        else:
            flash("bad username or password")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: Hmm, I feel your hash is not getting stored correctly in your DB. Looked at a few things, and you seem to be using Flask-Bcrypt correctly. What's the value of user.password?

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell this is the value of `user.password`   `'\\x24326224313224483352757749766438764134333757365142464f4f4f464959664d66673575467873754e466250716f3166375753696955556b2e36'
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you would like to encode your data before the hash: `password.encode('utf-8')`. If it comes as unicode it may raise errors.
Have a look here also: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/issues/9

Comment: Reading the current source of `flask-bcrypt`, the input is encoded automatically based on the current version of Python. So this is no longer necessary...

Comment: @SamuelJaeschke So what did you do to make it work? I've run into the same issue

Comment: @ralphie9224 I switched to a different worker supervisor, from Apache `mod_wsgi` to `uWSGI` with nginx. But it depends on your problem. What have you tried?

Comment: the answer from smewp below is a very small change to one line (in models.py of the user blueprint if you are using a typical flask app).

Comment: For me the answer was surprisingly simple.  The documentation states that for Python 3 you need to use method decode `pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(‘hunter2’).decode(‘utf-8’)` when you hash the password prior to storage.  https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 41):

My problem is similar to described by @tomClark

I use Postgres as my DDBB and his *driver*, or the DDBB system, encode **always** an **already encoded string**. The second encode process create an invalid hash like this:

```
'\\x24326224313224483352757749766438764134333757365142464f4f4f464959664d66673575‌​467873754e466250716f3166375753696955556b2e36'
```

A correct hash looks like this:

```
$2b$12$Wh/sgyuhro5ofqy2.5znc.35AjHwTTZzabz.uUOya8ChDpdwvROnm
```

To resolve it, I **decode** the hash to *utf8* first than save it to the DDBB.

Example code:

```
def set_password(self, pw):
    pwhash = bcrypt.hashpw(pw.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    self.password_hash = pwhash.decode('utf8') # decode the hash to prevent is encoded twice
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped :)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Comment: Great answer! With bcrypt==3.1.7 the following worked for me: `flask_bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf8')`

Comment: Solved it for me! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

You need to apply `.decode('utf-8')` to your `self.password`:

```
def set_password(self, password):
    """Set password."""
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: You Sir are a legend. Thanks. I am using the cookie cutter flask app with Python 3.5 and postgresql. Can't use a binary column as suggested above because it causes unicode errors. your suggestd change in models.py where set_password is works a charm.

Comment: Your solution works great

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the problem was related to a type conversion going on during password storage. Using `bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plaintext)` returns a binary value, like `b'$2b$12$zf/TxXZ4JJZ/lFX/BWALaeo0M.wNXrQXLqIFjmZ0WebqfVo9NES56'`.

Like mine was, your password column is set up as a string:

```
password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

I found that generating the hash above, storing that binary value it in my string password column, then simply retrieving it resulted in a different value due to SQLAlchemy's type conversion - nothing to do with bcrypt at all!

[A question on correct column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881169/what-column-type-length-should-i-use-for-storing-a-bcrypt-hashed-password-in-a-d) helped me realise that for correct roundtrip I had to store passwords as binary. Try replacing your column definition with:

```
password = db.Column(db.Binary(60), nullable=False)
```

I don't know for certain but suggest that different production environments and databases might handle this type conversion differently (reversibly in some cases, not in others), perhaps explaining the mixed success @Samuel Jaeschke has had.

This also explains why encoding the input string to a constrained character set (an earlier solution) might help in some cases and not others - if it causes the to/from type conversion to work then you'll recover the correct hash from the database for comparison.

At any rate, that solved this problem for me.

Comment: Great answer, solved my problem! Do you know why you have to store the value as a binary with postgres but can keep it a character with e.g. SQLite?

Comment: @Dominique Paul you could also store it as a string with postgres, you just have to do the right conversions so that when you roundtrip the value through the ORM you get the right thing back.

Answer (score 11):

It appears that this exception will also be returned if *anything* goes wrong while hashing a password.

From the `bcrypt` source for `hashpw()`:

```
hashed = _bcrypt.ffi.new("unsigned char[]", 128)
retval = _bcrypt.lib.crypt_rn(password, salt, hashed, len(hashed))

if not retval:
    raise ValueError("Invalid salt")
```

The `bcrypt` package (which `Flask-Bcrypt` uses to get the work done) returns `ValueError: Invalid salt` whenever the call to the OS's bcrypt lib returns an error. So if for some reason it is unable to invoke the bcrypt lib at all, it will still (incorrectly) return the `Invalid salt` error.

Seems to be a flaw in the `bcrypt` package implementation - it should check for specific values of `retval`.

---

In my case, the error turned out to be related running Flask under Apache `mod_wsgi` in a `virtualenv`. I could run flask directly without problems (using `flask-cli`), but the exact same app instance wouldn't successfully use `bcrypt` when running under `mod_wsgi`.

The problem was solved by modifying my Apache config to use the virtualenv as the main Python environment for `mod_wsgi`.

In `httpd.conf` or under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/...` add:

```
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/my/application-virtualenv
```

More information about this configuration can be found here: [Virtual Environments — mod_wsgi documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html)

I still suspect that my particular problem is related to something being shadowed by my system's python site-packages, or something else related to python includes.

---

**Edit:** Setting `WSGIPythonHome` turned out not to fix the problem. In the end I switched to *uWSGI* with *nginx*.

Comment: Regenerating the hash worked for me, but I forgot to save the original hash to see the difference.  It may be that I got the original hash from another machine using different versions of libraries.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are using python 3 and bcrypt0.7.1. first you have to delete the users in your database, then go to your models and add .decode('utf-8') to the generate_password_hash() method like so:

```
pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(‘hunter2’).decode('utf-8')
```

Alternatively you can uninstall flask-bcrypt==0.7.1 and install flask-bcrypt==0.62. Make sure you delete the users from the tables before installing flask-bcrypt==0.62

Comment: You cannot just delete the users from the table. It's like saying: "delete your application and create a new one". But you are right about the python and bcrypt versions.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. My code for checking the password was as follows:

```
if check_password_hash(form.password.data, user.pw_hashed):
```

When i reversed the order to:

```
if check_password_hash(user.pw_hashed, form.password.data):
```

It worked well.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem - got an: ValueError: Invalid salt - it turned out that in my models I had too few characters in my column:

```
password = Column(String(20))
```

In my database and models I had to change it to:

```
password = Column(String(100))
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
It turned out that the username and password combination I was trying to check was not hashed in the first place.
Make sure that the password for the username you are trying to check is already hashed and not plain text.
If the password is saved in plain text not hashed, you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

i found my own solution (postgresql):

1. use bytea data type for password.
2. when write password to db, use [convert_to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)
3. when read password from db, use [convert_from](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 1):

[thclark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3556110/thclark)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032208/5320906) - declare the password column as a binary type - is the most correct, but I thought I'd dig into what is happening, specifically with a Postgresql backend.

The problem is that the password hash generated by flask-bcrypt, when saved in a SQLAlchemy `String` column, is mysteriously transformed at some point, such that when the value retrieved from the database is passed to flask-bcrypt's `check_password_hash` function we get an `Invalid Salt` error.

The "transformation" occurs because it turns out that SQLAlchemy, as far as I can tell, does not require the values assigned to `String` or `Unicode` columns to be strings*.  Instead, the value is ultimately passed to the DBAPI connector - let's assume it psycopg2 in this case - and the connector tries to adapt the value to fit into whatever SQL SQLAlchemy has generated.

Psycopg2 [adapts binary values such as bytes](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#binary-adaptation) by converting them to the Postgresql [binary string representation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.9).  If the password column was declared as `LargeBinary` then the value would be round-tripped correctly.  As it is, the binary string representation is stored in the `String` column.  Thus `b'$2b$10$0Sfngi1XzpgxDkZPVcaolOHYu3h6IcN.ZHE4E8lWj0RuMGuVUvkHO'` becomes `'\x243262243130243053666e676931587a706778446b5a505663616f6c4f48597533683649634e2e5a48453445386c576a3052754d47755655766b484f'` in the database.

The binary string representation is essentially the bytes converted to hex, so converting between the two representations isn't too difficult:

```py
>>> bs = b'$2b$10$0Sfngi1XzpgxDkZPVcaolOHYu3h6IcN.ZHE4E8lWj0RuMGuVUvkHO'
>>> s = '\\x243262243130243053666e676931587a706778446b5a505663616f6c4f48597533683649634e2e5a48453445386c576a3052754d47755655766b484f'
>>> bs.hex() == s[2:]
True

>>> bytes.fromhex(s[2:]) == bs
True
```

So, the hash is being converted into a value suitable for insertion into a Postgresql `BYTEA` column, so we should declare our model's `password` column as `LargeBinary`, or `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.BYTEA`.

Encoding the password prior to hashing is redundant - flask-bcrypt does this [automatically](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/blame/27f982113c90dfda9a6e8a1e9173238458f70e24/flask_bcrypt.py#L154).

If you are stuck with the password column as a `String` then decoding the hash before writing to the database makes sense.  It's probably sufficient to decode as ASCII.

---

* I don't know why SQLAlchemy takes this lenient approach.  At a guess it's based on pragmatism: if you can insert bytes into `VARCHAR` columns using psycopg2, why should SQLAlchemy try to stop you?  At least you get a warning if you try it on a `Unicode` column.  Perhaps the arrival of type hints in SQLAlchemy 2.0 will change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You completely don't need `flask-bcrypt` for using `bcrypt`.

Just do something like this:

```
class User(Base):
    _password = db.Column("password", db.String, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, value):
        bvalue = bytes(value, 'utf-8')
        temp_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(bvalue, bcrypt.gensalt())
        self._password = temp_hash.decode('utf-8')

    def check_password(self, value):
        return bcrypt.checkpw(value.encode('utf-8'), self._password.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (invalid salt), but nobody here mentioned this solution.
Be aware with naming when creating a new bcrypt object:

As documentation states:

```
Namespacing Issues

It’s worth noting that if you use the format, bcrypt = Bcrypt(app) you are effectively overriding the bcrypt module. Though it’s unlikely you would need to access the module outside of the scope of the extension be aware that it’s overriden.

Alternatively consider using a different name, such as flask_bcrypt = Bcrypt(app) to prevent naming collisions.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to explore flask, and ran into the same issue when validating the hash -
I was passing the raw sql to db to get the hashed password, and then check it.
I realized after reading through here that sqlalchemy will return a tuple of values on query. So just looped through it and then passed the array index to.
It works, may be the issue was that we passed the tuple values to check_password. I am new to python so do let me know if I can improve or I have thought it correctly.

```
def post(self):
    name = request.form['EmailField1']
    secpass = request.form['password1']
    src_session = initialize_db()[0]
    query= ('select "Password" from login where "Email" =' )+("'%s'" ";") %(name)
    user = src_session.execute(query)
    users=user.fetchall()
    for user in users:
      authorized = password_hash.check_password(user[0],secpass)
      if not authorized:
         return {'error': 'Email or password invalid'}, 401
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had unhashed password for some users and when I tried to login with the unhashed password users, the app crashed. Just look at your DB or use another user.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the user you try to log in his password hashed in the database
if his password stored as plain text it will raise that error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31300500)