# sqlalchemy, postgres and unicode: why do I need to explicitly decode before storing in a string column?

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I am using the cookie cutter flask app with python 3.5 and postgresql. Postgresql is running on a docker image, with no config modifications.
psql tells me that the database is utf-8. I was getting string encoding errors until I used  `SQLALCHEMY_NATIVE_UNICODE = True`

The sqlalchemy column is:

```
  password = Column(db.String(256 ), nullable=True)
```

and the postgresql encoding is UTF-8

I was getting a Value Error invalid salt in a password validation. It seems that the database value is read and then converted to bytes encoded to UTF-8 before being sent to bcrypt for hash validation. It seems that the bcrypt functions work with bytes. Maybe bcrypt does this itself, when it gets a string, and perhaps it defaults to utf-8 (the code is not explicit about providing an encoding).

Be.low is the standard code which stores the hash. It takes the value returned by bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password), but however, it gets mangled later when it gets encoded.

```
def set_password(self, password):
        """Set password."""
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
```

and this fixes it:

```
def set_password(self, password):
        """Set password."""
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
```

I don't really understand how this is allowed. To get this to work I decode it, and then it gets handled by "something" which expects utf-8. When I don't give it utf-8, it should be an exception, shouldn't it?

related question: [flask-bcrypt - ValueError: Invalid salt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548846/flask-bcrypt-valueerror-invalid-salt)

Comment: It's unlikely you still care about this, but I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360362/5320906) the related question; some of the answer might be relevant to this question.