# How to fix sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation)?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I tried posting an an ad from my flask app but I keep getting this error from Heroku , even though it works locally

```
'2021-05-24T11:17:34.712097+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(100)
2021-05-24T11:17:34.712098+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-24T11:17:34.712100+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: INSERT INTO ads (condition, phone, category, description, brand, negotiable, price, city, post_by_id, image, image_name, mimetype, post_on) VALUES (%(condition)s, %(phone)s, %(category)s, %(description)s, %(brand)s, %(negotiable)s, %(price)s, %(city)s, %(post_by_id)s, %(image)s, %(image_name)s, %(mimetype)s, now()) RETURNING ads.id]
2021-05-24T11:17:34.712170+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'condition': 'new', 'phone': '97', 'category': 'electronics', 'description': 'kjiji', 'brand': 'iphone', 'negotiable': 'yes', 'price': '6.00', 'city': 'Accra', 'post_by_id': 1, 'image': b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x05V\x00\x00\x03\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xcf><\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x ... (1331901 characters truncated) ... 1l!+\x1d\xe9I6\xfa\x80*_n\xa7\x10\xf5c\x1e;\xf8:\xea\xb3c\xed\xd2+\xf3\xc6*\xa9\xbe\xbe\xde\xfe\x1f\x1e`\xa5\xb3\xc5S^Y\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82', 'image_name': 'Screenshot_4.png', 'mimetype': 'image/png'}]
2021-05-24T11:17:34.712395+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)
2021-05-24T11:17:34.714853+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.102.190.208 - - [24/May/2021:11:17:34 +0000] "POST /post_add HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://buykev.herokuapp.com/post" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.62"
2021-05-24T11:17:34.715971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/post_add" host=buykev.herokuapp.com request_id=ce4101c4-e93b-41ac-b2a8-cb4a534ffc6a fwd="154.160.4.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2459ms status=500 bytes=719 protocol=https
'
```

below is my database table

```py
class Ads(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key =True)
    condition = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    category = db.Column(db.String(100))
    description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    brand = db.Column(db.String(100))
    negotiable = db.Column(db.String(100))
    price = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(100))
    post_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    image = db.Column(db.String(100))
    image_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    mimetype =  db.Column(db.String(100))
    post_on = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `image` column is declared as being *character* data with a maximum length of 100, but you are passing considerably more than 100 bytes of *binary* data:

```py
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x05V\x00\x00\x03\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xcf><\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x ... (1331901 characters truncated) ... 1l!+\x1d\xe9I6\xfa\x80*_n\xa7\x10\xf5c\x1e;\xf8:\xea\xb3c\xed\xd2+\xf3\xc6*\xa9\xbe\xbe\xde\xfe\x1f\x1e\xa5\xb3\xc5S^Y\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB\x82'
```

Sine you are using Postgresql, you *could* declare `image` without specifying a length:

```py
image = db.Column(db.String)
```

but you may find that you have difficulties handling the data when returned from the database*.

It would be better to declare `image` as a BLOB (Binary Large OBject) type:

```py
image = db.Column(LargeBinary)
```

then SQLAlchemy should return bytes as expected when retrieving data.

If you change the column declaration for an existing database you will need to apply the change to the database itself, either using a tool like [Flask Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), or directly in the psql console:

```sql
 ALTER TABLE ads ALTER COLUMN image TYPE bytea USING image::bytea;
```

---

* This will work for sqlite, but will not round-trip correctly in Postgresql - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360362/5320906) for more discussion around this.