# Why is my uploaded image not showing on heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I recently a Flask webapp on Heroku. Images are uploaded to the database into a `Text` column. On my development machine using SQLite this is working fine. But on Heroku with postgres the images fail to show.

```py
class Ads(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key =True)
    image = db.Column(db.Text)

@app.route('/get_image/<int:id>')
def get_image(id):
    img = db.session.query(Ads).filter_by(id=id).first()
    return Response(img.image)
```

```
{% for row in imb %}
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <p><strong>{{row.brand}}</strong></p>
        <img src="{{url_for('get_image',id = row.id)}}"  alt="doctor" width="250" height="100">
        <p><strong>  {{row.price}} , {{row.category}}  </strong>
        <p><strong>  {{row.description}}  </strong>
        <a href="/update/{{row.id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit{{row.id}}" ><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x" ></i></a>
        <a href="/delete/{{row.id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></a>  
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Writing bytes to text columns will not behave as you expect in Postgresql, as I pointed out when [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67683055/5320906) your previous question.  Sqlite is more lenient than Postgresql in this respect, that's why it works locally.

Comment: Thanks I just read it this morning